# iOS title on wrong button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uibutton, cgrect

I have a pretty strange problem. In one view I have three buttons, each with an image and a title. First button is OK, second only shows an image, and the third shows the right image, but the title from `Button 2`. Like below:

```
------------
I  Image 1 I
I  Title 1 I
------------

------------
I  Image 2 I
I          I
------------

------------
I  Image 3 I
I  Title 2 I
------------
```

I can't find what is causing this.

I have a UIButton subclass with a custom init method that looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withImage:(UIImage *)image andTitle:(NSString *)title
{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIImageView *icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        icon.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        CGRect iconFrame = icon.frame;
        iconFrame.origin.x = frame.size.width / 2 - iconFrame.size.width / 2;
        iconFrame.origin.y = 5;
        iconFrame.size.height = frame.size.height / 2.5;
        icon.frame = iconFrame;

        [self addSubview:icon];

        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TisaMobiPro" size:14];
        [titleLabel setText:title];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:1.000 blue:1.000 alpha:0.5];
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        CGRect titleFrame = titleLabel.frame;
        titleFrame.origin.y = icon.frame.origin.y + icon.frame.size.height;
        titleFrame.size.height = frame.size.height / 2;
        titleLabel.frame = titleFrame;
        [self addSubview:titleLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I add the buttons like this:

```
int numberOfButtons = 3;

CGRect mentionRect = CGRectMake(0, 10,self.menuContainer.frame.size.width / numberOfButtons, self.menuContainer.frame.size.height - 10);
self.mentionButton = [[CustomBarButton alloc] initWithFrame:mentionRect withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/Mentions.png"] andTitle:@"Mention"];
[self.menuContainer addSubview:self.mentionButton];


CGRect hashRect = CGRectMake(mentionRect.origin.x + mentionRect.size.width, 10,self.menuContainer.frame.size.width / numberOfButtons, self.menuContainer.frame.size.height - 10);
self.hashtagButton = [[CustomBarButton alloc] initWithFrame:hashRect withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/HashTagIcon.png"] andTitle:@"Hashtag"];
[self.menuContainer addSubview:self.hashtagButton];


CGRect photoRect = CGRectMake(hashRect.origin.x + hashRect.size.width, 10, self.menuContainer.frame.size.width / numberOfButtons, self.menuContainer.frame.size.height - 10);
self.photoButton = [[CustomBarButton alloc] initWithFrame:photoRect withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/CameraIcon.png"] andTitle:@"Photo"];
[self.menuContainer addSubview:self.photoButton];
```

Can anyone find what is causing this, or have any idea on what I can do to solve it?

Comment: Check the frame setting in `UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];`. You should change that frame.

Comment: That is based on where you need to put it. Try giving a static frame first and check how it comes. Then modify it according to your requirement. Don't give `frame` as its frame. Fix the origin.x value to a constant first and check.

Comment: Ok, mmm. The weird thing is that I use this `UIButton`subclass in another view, and there it works. But I will try.

Comment: That could be because you are passing frame.origin.x as zero in those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the frame setting in `UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];`. You should not set frame as `frame` which is an input param in init method. Try to set a static frame and then modify according to your requirement to put it where ever you need it in that view. Basically your `origin.x` value is going wrong and that is why you are getting weird output.